# Google Cloud Console "loading" forever

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

When I go to the Google Cloud console for my project today and click on "Compute Engine" or "Cloud Storage," it just says "loading" forever. A few days ago, I was able to see my VMs and storage buckets. Is there any way to get the console working again?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think possibly there is something tying up Google Cloud/Drive. Mine is behaving the exact same way. I think that it is an issue with Google, have you tried any other google services that are being slow? ALL the google stuff is being extremely slow on my ENVY 17 with 12GB Ram and 1TB HD so at least in my case its not a memory issue or cluttered issue.

One thing try clearing out your system junk files. Under Control Panel>System> you should see ADVANCED SYSTEM SETTINGS and that should have an option to delete unneccessary files. (Cookies, Browser History, other temp files).

Comment: You were right. Just started working again on its own. Thanks!